# CSS: inline-block not on the same line as float with boxsize

Tags: html, css

I was experimenting with using boxsize and inline-block vs float.
 I am stumped as to why I get different results for the following:

[Codepen - float](http://codepen.io/Lembasts/pen/fplzg)

[Codepen - Inline-block](http://codepen.io/Lembasts/pen/JGdek)

More specifically - why does the inline-block wrap? If I use Chrome's developer tool it reports both "left" and "right" divs as 240 pixels wide.

Thanks

Comment: font-size:0 for container will help

Comment: it's because of whitespace created by inline elements check this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xaEiz

Comment: wow so many identical answers.. someone must be right ;]

Comment: @webkit, just different ways of putting the same thing. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inline-block` elements flow just like text does, so the newline character between the two divs is rendered as a space character, which makes the total width (left div + space + right div) greater than 100%.

The below example will behave as expected even with `inline-block`.

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="boxsize">Left</div><div class="boxsize">Right</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Another method is to use comments to remove the whitespace, which can help with indentation.

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="boxsize">Left</div><!--
--><div class="boxsize">Right</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone - so subtle this css stuff sometimes!

Comment: That's true. A lot of unexpected things happen. Also, please accept an answer?

Comment: My apologies - I have only just signed up and didnt know about the answer accept thing - thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Lembasts, no matter. :) Also, you might want to take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125208/when-exactly-do-i-get-comment-notifications

Answer (score 0):

`display:inline-block` adds extra pixels as spacing between two elements.One of the option is to make it not to display them. Your html:

```
<div class="boxsize">Left</div><!--spacing-->
<div class="boxsize">Right</div>
```

Without spacing :

```
<div class="boxsize">Left</div
><div class="boxsize">Right</div>
```

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/swIom)

Answer (score 0):

When using `inline-block`, white spacing are shown as a space.

use `float` or remove white spaces between left&right `div`s.

Answer (score 0):

As you see in the "Codepen - Inline-block" code. Inline-block act as a new line character. it does not allow the other fields to align together. To wrap the fields you need to remove the spaces between the `<div class="boxsize">Left</div>  <div class="boxsize">Right</div> to <div class="boxsize">Left</div><div class="boxsize">Right</div>`

Answer (score 0):

A floated element (typically the space between text) would be prevented form wrapping. and a `inline-block` element preserve the white-space.

There are several way exist to prevent this problem.

[Read This](http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block)

Here the example of `white-space: nowrap;`:

```
div.container {
 width:30em;
 border:10px solid;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```