# CSS: all sub-div elements on one line with centerder 2nd element

Tags: css

i am attempting to align 3 sub-div elements in one line, first element with left floating, third - with right and 2nd - centered.
Below my draft. What I have missed?
http://jsfiddle.net/yDzL9/

In my real e-shop the problem is in aligning of 2nd div which contains `input (button)`, but in jsfiddle's example the problem with the third div.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `display: flex` css rule it will work as you want it to!

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="wishlist"></div>
    <div class="cart"></div>
    <div class="compare"></div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    height:26px;
    width:300px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    background-color:green;
}

#container > div {
    height: 90%;
    width: 90px;
}

.wishlist {
    float: left;
    background-color:blue;
}

.cart {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:yellow;
}

.compare {
    float: right;
    background-color:red;
}
```

As shown in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yDzL9/12/), and here is [another one](http://jsfiddle.net/yDzL9/13/).

Comment: it is not suitable as 2nd div must be centered but `margin:0 auto;` doesn't work. See updated [link](http://jsfiddle.net/yDzL9/4/)

Comment: @Andry You missed `display: flex;` from your container. If you do that, it works: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yDzL9/14/)

Comment: I know about flex. Problem in support in Safari and old browsers :)

Comment: `display: -webkit-box;` `display: -moz-box;` `display: -ms-flexbox;` `display: -webkit-flex;` `display: flex;` should make it work for most browsers but maybe early versions of IE will have trouble **OFC**.

Answer (score 1):

Use display: `inline-block` for all sub elements and set `white-space: nowrap;` property to parent div.

Example-

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="wishlist">
    </div>
        <div class="cart">
    </div>
        <div class="compare">
    </div>    
</div>
```

**Method 1 (Without Floated div):**

CSS:

```
#container {
    height:26px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:#009900; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}


#container div{
    display: inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:26px;
}
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yDzL9/5/)

**Method 2 (With Floated div)**

CSS:

```
#container {
    height:26px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:#009900; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}

#container div{
    display: inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:26px;
}

.wishlist{
    background-color:blue; 
    float: left;
}

.cart{
    background-color:black; 
}

.compare{
    background-color:red; 
    float: right;
}
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yDzL9/6/)

Comment: Heh, I have just modified my real project with first solution. Works as expected. I did not know about white-space, it was my problem :-(

Comment: @Andry: Actually 'inline-block' preserve  the white spaces. So for overcome the problem of unwanted white space i used white-space: nowrap property, There are several of way exist for this. See http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block Also see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134034/css-inline-block-not-on-the-same-line-as-float-with-boxsize/24134211#24134211